# Why is my simple RoutePrefix failing with Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/UserProfile/{id}")]
    public class UserProfileController : ApiController
    {
        private IdentityContext db = new IdentityContext();

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMapData()
        {
```

I am calling this with the following call but it's returning not found.

```
GET /api/UserProfile/GetMapData HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I followed the docs and set up:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "Route["GetMapData"]" attribute on the action in this case...RoutePrefix attribute doesn't add any routes to the route table and hence you are seeing this behavior...its only for supplying any prefix to any Route attributes present on the actions...

Answer (score 0):

`[RoutePrefix]` adds a **prefix** to your routes.

So in your example, if you don't specify the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute, then by convention your route would be:

```
~/UserProfile/GetMapData
```

By adding the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute you are saying that the routes in this controller will be prefixed by the specified route.

i.e. you are effectively changing your route to:

```
~/api/UserProfile/{id}/UserProfile/GetMapData
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If all you want to do is add the "api" prefix then change your prefix to:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
```

See more details about attribute routing [here](http://attributerouting.net/#route-prefixes).